# trying to use a loop to buffer around multiple feature classes at once (arcgis using arcpy)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, buffer, loop

I am using ArcPy to work within a geodatabase in ArcGIS Pro. I need to create a buffer around all the feature classes of a certain type listed in a previous line of code. `well_path_list` lists all the feature classes which need a buffer, but it is a string. Here is what I have so far, I am unsure how to progress?

```py
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Scripting_Class/midterm/Oil_Project.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
parcel_layer = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer('Parcels',"outparcel")
well_path_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type= "Polyline",feature_dataset = "Well_Data")
for well_path in well_path_list:
```

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/74188963

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for well_path in well_path_list: # Start the loop
    outfc = arcpy.Describe(well_path).baseName + '_buffered' # Take original shapefile name and add '_buffered'
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(well_path, r"C:\Users\output\buffered\{}".format(outfc), # Define individual outputname for each well_path
                         "100 Feet", "FULL", "ROUND", "LIST")
```